# Mark incoming SMS as Read in Default SMS Application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, default

Sorry if i did not come up with a suitable title.
I want to know that is it possible to mark SMS as read in the default SMS Application through my Application?
i.e. i am developing my own application in which i am storing sms that are not from the contact list but the problem is that when ever sms received it received on my app and also on the default sms app so i want that when ever sms received then i can mark the sms as read(of the default SMS App) so that there is no need for go to default sms app and mark SMS as read.
Can i do that from my Application?

Comment: "Can i do that from my Application?" - No. Unless you're just on KitKat, in which case there's a workaround.

Comment: Yes you can do that using content provider, as soon as you are getting sms in your application it will not be added in the db. so you need to wait untill that sms is entered in the db. So you need to start service after sometime of the sms received.

Comment: @SilvansSolanki Can you provide any link that can help me in that problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private void markMessageASRead(Context context, String numb, String body) {

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try{

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                if ((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")).equals(number)) && (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")) == 0)) {
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith(body)) {
                        String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put("read", true);
                        context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" + SmsMessageId, null);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("Mark Read", "Error in Read: "+e.toString());
  }
```

}

Comment: Ok lemme try that sir

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, unless invoked in the default messaging app itself.